# Will structure blocks load structures from another world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have some redstone I want to transfer from one world to another. I'm planning on using structure blocks, but do structure blocks load structures even if it comes from a different world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. That's one of their main features.

Answer (score 3):

Structure blocks are used to save structures within a world into a file, so you can load them into other worlds. They are for copying structures to other worlds. So yes, that is what they are for. If you need more info check out the [wiki page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Structure_Block).